# Simulate mousemove on webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript

It is possible to simulate (not imitation) mousemove on web page with javascript?

Maybe something like this? :

mousemove(100, 100)

mousemove(110, 110)

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the mousepointer using JavaScript.
The security implications (not to mention usability) would be terrible, were this possible.
For example, malicious websites could trick users into doing (and downloading) all sorts of things.